# Sort-of Software Raid-1 on windows?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, backup, sync, network-shares

I have 2 windows vista computers on a lan, can i set them up with a program so that they replicate the data written in one partition to another and the other way around. basically replicating data across 2 partitions whenever each is modified. Making that data is available on the network when either of the computers are turned on, when both are, data is synchronized. Is this posible?

Comment: By partitions, are you referring to duplicating the files in one computer to the other and other way around or actually doing something in the partition level? Maybe you should open up your situation a bit more.

Comment: removing [raid-1] tag since this is less about RAID and more about synchronizing separate partitions at a file/folder level.

Answer (score 0):

You could run [`rsync`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) on one (or both) computer and sync needed files with it.

[cwrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650) is a bundle of Cygwin and rsync for Windows, if you feel it unnecessary to install Cygwin by itself. There are also good instructions [how to set up `rsyncd`](http://www.gaztronics.net/rsync.php) with full Cygwin environment.

For rsync client there is [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) that is described as a "Windows friendly" version of rsync.

Note, that this replication method needs to be triggered e.g. by Windows scheduling or Cygwin's `cron`and is not going to be nowhere near real-time solution.